# Wrong number of classes in Keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Keras is finding a wrong number of classes in train and test set folders. I have 3 classes, but it keeps saying that there are 4. Can anyone help me, please?

Here the code:

```
cnn = Sequential()

cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

cnn.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

#Full connection
cnn.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN
cnn.compile(optimizer = OPTIMIZER, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


     #Fitting
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                       shear_range = 0.2,
                                       zoom_range = 0.2,
                                       horizontal_flip = True)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                     target_size = tgt_size,
                                                     batch_size = batch_size,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical')

    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                                target_size = tgt_size,
                                                batch_size = batch_size,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')
```

And the error:

```
Found 12000 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 3000 images belonging to 4 classes.

Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_15 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 4)
```

EDIT:

It only happens with Jupyter Notebook in Google Cloud. When I use Spyder locally, it finds the correct number of classes.

Comment: Did you try Flatten before the first Dense layer?

Comment: Each folder is one class, so how many folders do you have in the training_set and test_set folders?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have 4 folders.

Comment: Then keras will see 4 classes, why do you think you have three classes?

Comment: That's the thing, when I work with 4 classes it says I have 5, when I have 3, it finds 4. lol

Comment: @NormanZhu,Yes, I tried to, but it's still finding one more class than I have.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al dataset/training_set`?

Comment: ['.ipynb_checkpoints', 'dogs', 'person', 'birds', 'cats']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you might have found out by yourself by now, Jupyter creates hidden checkpoint folders for backup purposes. That's why there is always one class (as in folder) extra when using flow_from_directory.
The simplest solution would be to just delete that hidden folder.

Comment: For me, this was a __pycache__ folder from having an __init__.py in there.  But same reason.

Answer (score 4):

For people still having issues with this on google colab. As stated above by bennyOoO, 
" Jupyter creates hidden checkpoint folders for backup purposes. That's why there is always one class (as in folder) extra when using flow_from_directory."

```
import os
import shutil

os.listdir("/content/some_data/or_some_train_data") #First find where the ".ipynb_checkpoints" is located.

shutil.rmtree("directory_where_.ipynb_checkpoints_is_located/.ipynb_checkpoints") #be careful with shutil.rmtree() because it deletes every tree in that path. In other words, do not make mistakes.
```